# Unable to add/synchronise Apple developer account to Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-code, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ipa

I am not able to add My developer account in Visual Studio for Mac. I am trying to perform automatic provisioning and select my team Id, however I am not able to add the developer account.

Path--> Visual Studio - Preferences - Apple developer Accounts

Visual studio 2019 for mac-version 8.3.2(build 2)
ios visual-studio-mac apple-developer-account

In a lot of threads I see that once the user name and password is given and when the sign in button is clicked from the popup (refer below image), people were getting Failed to Synchronise error. But in my case the pop just disappears immediately without even throwing the error. And I don't see the account getting added up.
Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hi, whether this occurs before? And you can update to the laest Visual Studio 2019 for Mac version 8.7.6 to chech whether can add Apple Account.

Comment: No, I am trying it for the first time. It wasn't getting updated earlier.@JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: Okey, you could update the VS for Mac to the latest version to check whtether the apple account can be added.

Comment: Thanks, @Junior Jiang updating VS, Xcode, and macOS to the latest fixed this.

Comment: still today in the latest version this problem exist.